# Replicate NSApp -runModalForWindow:

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

I want to replicate NSApp's -runModalForWindow: method without having the rest of my application rendered useless. I want to lock out the user for a period of time using an NSWindow, have my application do a bunch of things, then close the NSWindow.

I know how to open the NSWindow on its own but disabling other windows that are open is the challenge. Is this achievable?

Thanks in advance.
Ricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-[NSApplication beginModalSessionForWindow:]` and friends should do the trick:

```
NSModalSession session = [NSApp beginModalSessionForWindow:modalWindow];
while (1) {
    if ([NSApp runModalSession:session] != NSRunContinuesResponse)
        break;
    // do stuff
}
[NSApp endModalSession:session];
```

Note that it’s usually a good idea to do your “bunch of things” in the background, i. e. using Grand Central Dispatch.

Comment: Of course, if you're doing other things on background threads, whether using GCD or using threads directly, then you might as well just use `runModalForWindow:`.